# Azure Batch - problems with Active Directory authentication

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-batch

I'm following [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756780/azure-batch-pool-how-do-i-use-a-custom-vm-image-via-python?noredirect=1#comment81073467_46756780) about creating Azure Batch pools with custom machine images. I'm stuck on the Azure Active Directory (AD) authentication. I've followed all the tutorials on the other thread for registering an application and obtaining the application id, tenant id, and private key.

Here's the standard bit for creating the Batch Client:

```
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=APP_CLIENT_ID,
        secret=APP_CLIENT_KEY,
        tenant=APP_TENANT_ID,
        resource='https://batch.core.windows.net'
    )
    self._batch_client = batch.BatchServiceClient(credentials, base_url=BATCH_ACCOUNT_URL)
```

Here is the code for creating a pool:

```
    # Get details for configuring worker machines with the node image file
    node_agents = self._batch_client.account.list_node_agent_skus()
    image_agent = next(agent for agent in node_agents if 'ubuntu 16.04' in agent.id)
    image_ref = batchmodels.ImageReference(virtual_machine_image_id='/subscriptions/<long_URL>')
    virtual_machine_config = batchmodels.VirtualMachineConfiguration(
        image_reference=image_ref,
        node_agent_sku_id=image_agent.id
    )

    # Define an admin user account for the worker machines
    user = batchmodels.AutoUserSpecification(
        scope=batchmodels.AutoUserScope.pool,
        elevation_level=batchmodels.ElevationLevel.admin
    )

    # Define the pool
    new_pool = batch.models.PoolAddParameter(
        id=self.id,
        virtual_machine_configuration=virtual_machine_config,
        vm_size=self._vm_size,
        target_dedicated_nodes=self.nodes,
        start_task=batch.models.StartTask(
            command_line=start_commands,
            user_identity=batchmodels.UserIdentity(auto_user=user),
            wait_for_success=True,
            resource_files=self._resource_files),
    )

    # Instantiate the pool
    try:
        self._batch_client.pool.add(new_pool)
        self._created = True
    except batchmodels.batch_error.BatchErrorException as err:
        print_batch_exception(err)
        raise
```

This triggers the following error output on the 3rd line, when trying to create `image_agent`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Echo\Code\pysource\Pysource\dataIO\Tests\TestAzure.py", line 170, in test_create_and_destroy_pool
    pool.create(data=res_folder)
  File "C:\Echo\Code\pysource\Pysource\dataIO\azureUtils.py", line 440, in create
    image_agent = next(agent for agent in node_agents if 'ubuntu 16.04' in agent.id)
  File "C:\Echo\Code\pysource\Pysource\dataIO\azureUtils.py", line 440, in <genexpr>
    image_agent = next(agent for agent in node_agents if 'ubuntu 16.04' in agent.id)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\msrest\paging.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.advance_page()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\msrest\paging.py", line 95, in advance_page
    self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\batch\operations\account_operations.py", line 119, in internal_paging
    raise models.BatchErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.batch.models.batch_error.BatchErrorException: {'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly.\nRequestId:1a38e970-fb6e-4d2e-b691-5c47f46186b1\nTime:2017-11-02T19:42:54.0264686Z'}
```

...with attached HTTP log:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS 

connection (1): <batch_name>.westus.batch.azure.com
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: DEBUG: https://<batch_name>.westus.batch.azure.com:443 "GET /nodeagentskus?api-version=2017-09-01.6.0 HTTP/1.1" 401 529
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Request URL: 'https://<batch_name>.westus.batch.azure.com/nodeagentskus?api-version=2017-09-01.6.0'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Request method: 'GET'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Request headers:
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Accept': 'application/json'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Connection': 'keep-alive'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'User-Agent': 'python/3.5.2 (Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0) requests/2.14.0 msrest/0.4.18 msrest_azure/0.4.15 batchserviceclient/4.0.0 Azure-SDK-For-Python'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'client-request-id': '03663a50-c006-11e7-b93e-847beb5642f2'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'accept-language': 'en-US'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Authorization': '*****'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; charset=utf-8'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Request body:
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: None
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Response status: 401
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Response headers:
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Content-Length': '529'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'request-id': '1a38e970-fb6e-4d2e-b691-5c47f46186b1'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'DataServiceVersion': '3.0'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is missing or invalid."'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG:     'Date': 'Thu, 02 Nov 2017 19:42:53 GMT'
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: Response content:
msrest.http_logger: DEBUG: b'{\r\n  "odata.metadata":"https://<batch_name>.westus.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{\r\n    "lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly.\\nRequestId:1a38e970-fb6e-4d2e-b691-5c47f46186b1\\nTime:2017-11-02T19:42:54.0264686Z"\r\n  },"values":[\r\n    {\r\n      "key":"AuthenticationErrorDetail","value":"Could not find identity for access token."\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}'
msrest.exceptions: DEBUG: {'lang': 'en-US', 'value': 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly.\nRequestId:1a38e970-fb6e-4d2e-b691-5c47f46186b1\nTime:2017-11-02T19:42:54.0264686Z'}
```

The key message is this: **"key":"AuthenticationErrorDetail","value":"Could not find identity for access token."**

Note that if I hard-code the `node_agent_sku_id` the error moves from line 3 to the line just below the `try` statement, when attempting to add the new pool.

How can I begin to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: It seems like `user error` some cred detail not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource for Azure Batch should be `'https://batch.core.windows.net/'` (note the trailing slash).